# how to sort vector of pair decreasing order in C++?

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

Trying to sort an `vector<pair<int,int>>` decreasing order in C++.

```
sort(v.begin(),v.end(),greater<int> ())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elements of your vector are `pair<int,int>`, so you should use `greater<pair<int,int>> ()` instead of `greater<int> ()`.